# Should I update version of assembly if only reference version changed?

Tags: c#, nuget, nuget-package

I have AssemblyA with version 1.0.0 and AssemblyB with Version 1.0.0. AssemblyB references AssemblyA and I create NuGet packages of both assemblies.

Now, I've made a bug fix in AssemblyA and it gets version 1.0.1. Should I now update AssemblyB also to 1.0.1 cause of the changed reference or should I only update the version if I have changes in code?

The NuGet packages are only used in a local feed (company wide).

What are the pro and cons of both solutions?
My pro is, that I do not reference an old, buggy package and when I use both assemblies in ApplicationC, I have only to reference and update AssemblyB. But it feels cringe, to update a version number without any changes in code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given MyCoolPackage 1.0.0 having a dependency on MyPoorDependency 1.0.0, and you having bugfixed MyPoorDependency to 1.0.1, then yes, an updated dependency for a package means a new version of that package.

If you only publish the dependency update, MyCoolPackage 1.0.0's metadata will still point to MyPoorDependency 1.0.0. Users of your package won't know there's an update for its dependencies. They can have their package manager set up to only install the lowest common denominator of dependencies or even pinned the version to MyPoorDependency 1.0.0. Because after all, that's what your MyCoolPackage 1.0.0 says it'll work with.

For this the package manager looks at all your users' project dependencies, will see that it requires MyCoolPackage 1.0.0, which has a dependency on MyPoorDependency 1.0.0, and it **won't update**.

So yes, update MyCoolPackage to require MyPoorDependency 1.0.1 and release an new version, probably also 1.0.1.

Comment: I don't think this answer could be characterised as "opinion based" so I query whether the question should have been closed on that basis... Hence I'm voting to reopen the question.

Comment: @Matthew thanks, me too. People read "should I" and go straight for the close button. It's answerable with facts and therefore not opinion-based, voted to reopen. See Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/408511/why-was-my-question-closed-as-opinion-based-when-im-asking-how-to-solve-a-sp/408522#comment849990_408522